# Click: Test click.group commands without running their code

Tags: testing, command-line-interface, pytest, python-click

I´m currently writing tests for my application and therefore, I have to test some `click.group` commands I defined:

Let´s say I defined them like:

```
@click.group(cls=MyGroup)
@click.pass_context
def myapp(ctx):
    init_stuff()    

@myapp.command()
@click.option('--myOption')
def foo(myOption: str) -> None:
    do_stuff() # change some files, print, create other files
```

I know that I could use the `CliRunner from click.testing`. However, I just want to make sure, that the command is called, but I DONT WANT it to execute any code (for example by applying the `CliRunner.invoke()`).

How could this be done? 
I couldn´t come up with a solution using mocking with `foo` for example. Or do I have to execute code lets say using the `isolated_filesystem()` which `CliRunner` provides?

So the question is: What would be the most efficient way to test my commands when defined like shown above?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to unittest the click framework?   Why would you suppose the framework is not working correctly?

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks for your comment. Y I should have clarified this. I dont want to test the framework; but now as I´m reading your comment, it seems testing only the calls is useless. I think I will actually test the commands instead of just their invocation with click. This seems much more reasonable. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `--dry-run` flag to your group or some commands, and save it it inside the context, and if the flag is enabled, do not execute any code. Then you can use `CliRunner.invoke()` with the `--dry-run` flag enabled and just check your invocations have happened, without actually executing the code.

Comment: hey, thanks again ;). Yes my initial intention was, that I want the command to be called even if the command was not spelled correct: Like given `fooz` I implemented it to recognize it as `foo`. That´s what I wanted to test and seems your idea would be the way to go for this.